# Reposting duplicate content on websites

Tags: seo, blogs, canonical-link

A contact of ours would like to repost our blog content on their website but I’ve always been told not to do this as it would be seen as duplicate content by google and hurt our SEO and drive traffic away. Is this correct?

Comment: @Cherubim it's off topic for meta.  He's asking about reposting his blog's content on some other website. Also, unless you're 1000% sure it's on topic for another SE site, don't bother recommending someone repost elsewhere.

Comment: @Cherubim thanks.  Unless you're a long time member of another site, it's really hard to know exactly what is and is not welcome there.  Believe me, I follow that rule as well, as I've done the same thing.  Multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed bad practice. Google is good at picking up who posted the article first and who has the duplicate content. If your contact is ok with it they can add a canonical tag pointing to the page that they took the content from that will make clear to google that they do not want rankings from doing so and that the original content is at your page.

Regards